# How to display a title over an image?

Tags: interface-design

What's the best way to put a title on top of an image?

I'm exploring the following options.

[image: options]

The image and title will be user submitted which make things a little bit harder.

The specific question is, what's the criteria I should use to pick one over the other.

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked? Are you asking for a "poll"? That is typically off-topic on Stack Exchange sites. Surely you know that.

Comment: I recon that came out poorly. It's not exactly a poll but a question on how to use a title over an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I'm paying attention, I've seen a lot of sites use a faded gradient below the text. It works well with clear images and of course with dark ones:

[image: using faded gradient below text]

Answer (score 3):

Why squeeze it? As a phone screen can scroll down as much as needed, i would eliminate the dilemma and just move the title BELOW the picture. That way you'll always have black text on a white background and without this ever touching the actual picture.

Comment: That's what I've seen. Another option I saw in https://google.com/travel is to add a black gradient on the background  https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1wSn.jpg

Comment: Yeap, faded gradient also a good option because it provides contrast behind the white text.

Answer (score 1):

Contrast between the image and the text is the primary concern. Images 1 and 3 effectively deal with this. (The second choice ought to be eliminated as there will be times when this solution fails spectacularly.)

A second concern, not addressed in the examples, are longer titles.  You could use a band but consider, in your design, that the title may be 3 or 4 lines.